# Remove columns from a matrix after performing a computation

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix A with 10 values.

And each of these values exist in separate cells:

```
A = [A{1}, A{2}, A{3}, A{4}, A{5}, A{6}, A{7}, A{8}, A{9}, A{10}
```

Suppose I apply a strange made-up function to this matrix (strangef, please don't worry too much about what this function actually does! ;) ) which ends up giving me 10 non-identical values:

```
B = strangef(A);
B(1,:) = [1.3, 4.2, 1.0, 2.3, 6.4, 0.9, 4.5, 2.6, 7.1, 3.1]
```

Then I look to find the minimum value in B:

```
c = find(B==min(min(B)))
```

I find that it's the 6th value of A, so now I want to reconstruct my matrix so that it excludes this 6th value, as in:

```
A = [A{1}, A{2}, A{3}, A{4}, A{5}, A{7}, A{8}, A{9}, A{10}]
```

I can construct this new matrix using an index as follows:

```
col = 10; %number of columns
index = setdiff(1:col, c);
```

However while I can use the c (column value) on the first iteration of the loop my new matrix is missing one value if the minimum value of this new matrix is A{3} the column value in this new matrix that has only 9 columns is 2.

Therefore I actually end up creating this matrix:

```
A = [A{1}, A{3}, A{4}, A{5}, A{7}, A{8}, A{9}, A{10}]
```

rather than this one:

```
A = [A{1}, A{2}, A{4}, A{5}, A{7}, A{8}, A{9}, A{10}]
```

Here's some pseudocode

```
excludingMinimums = [];
col = 10;

while col>1
      index = setdiff(1:col,excludingMinimum)
      for i = 1:col
          A = [A{i}]
      end
      B = strangef(A)
      c = find(B==min(min(B)))
      excludingMinimums = [excludingMinimums, c]
      col = col - 1; 
end
```

Comment: Question and yes it's about "strangef" - If we introduce `NaNs` into `A` after every run of that function, would that be a problem? Would that affect the results of `B = strangef(A);`, except that the corresponding element in `B` would be `NaN` too? Would that affect other values in `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this instead: keep a running copy of your shrinking A.  Deleting is easier than reconstructing with missing elements.

```
while size(A,2)>1
    B = strangef(A);
    c = find(min(min(B)));
    A(c) = [];   % delete the element from A
    excludingMinimums = [excludingMinimums c];  % save this vector for future output?
end
```

Note the `()` notation for deletion, even though `A` is a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Logical indexing makes it much simpler than you think:

```
B = strangef(A);
A = A(:, B~=min(B));
```

We can keep track of the remaining columns similarly:

```
col = 1:size(A,2);
while length(col)>1
    B = strangef(A);
    idx = (B == min(B));
    col = col(idx);
    A = A(:, ~idx);
end
```